# Could I always compare two Immutable.Map using Map.equals() ? The computational complexity is really different than "===" on two identical objects?

Tags: dictionary, complexity-theory, equals, immutable.js

I would like to understand the computational complexity of an Immutable.equals().
I haven't clearly found my answer by reading the source code, an neither in web discutions...

```
var obj1 = Immutable.Map({a: 1, b: 2, c: 'lot of entries'});
var obj2 = obj1.set('a', 1);
```

**Does `obj1.equals(obj2)` will compare every key of the objects even if there are equals?**
If it compares every key, I would better compare it with `obj1===obj2`.
Does Immutable verify the === equality before comparing every keys/values of the objects?
In the case of two identical objects, it would be interesting to know if there is a big difference between the computational complexity of an Immutable.equals() and the === operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two concepts at play here: identity and equality. `===` on `Object`s returns `true` when both sides refer to the same object. For example:

```
var x = {};
var y = {};
var z = x;

# x and y have the same keys and values but are two different objects.
x === y # => false

# x and z refer to the same object
x === z # => true
```

We can conclude that **if `x` and `y` refer to the same object then they should be equal**. This indeed is [what `immutable.js` does when comparing two objects](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/master/src/utils/deepEqual.js#L21).

The reverse is not true. You can have two equal objects that aren't identical. The most trivial example is:

```
var x = new Map({ name: 'Greg' });
var y = new Map({ name: 'Greg' });

# x and y are two different objects
x === y # => false

# x and y are equal, i.e. they have equal keys and values
x.equals(y) # => true
```

To sum up: `equals` (as implemented by `immutable.js`) always does the `===` check so it'll take at least the same amount of time. **You need to keep in mind the difference between equality and identity and use either `===` or `equals` accordingly**.

Comment: Thank you ! I was yet aware about the difference between equality and identity but I didn't know that `Immutable.equals` checks the identity before performing deep-equal checks. Your link is perfectly clear : identity is checked before all. That fully clear now ! :-)